# What to do when someone keeps creating new accounts to ask the same bad question?

Tags: discussion

Someone has asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27240004/3651800

Later on the same day a new user with a very similar username posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27240606/3651800

This *might* just be a case of two students who are doing the same course and looking to have their homework assignment done by Stack Overflow stooges, but I get the impression this is the same person with a different user account.

I know we are supposed to downvote *Questions* rather than *people*, but is it acceptable for someone to open multiple accounts to ask the same poor question over and over?

And if we suspect this is happening, is there an appropriate/recommended course of action to take?

Note that I tried flagging the questions as duplicates, but I could not because there were no upvoted or accepted answers for either question.

Comment: Related: [Duo of buddies can circumvent duplicate closures under the new rule requiring an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171371)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just flag it for moderator attention.
They can see more data/info etc than we can.

---

[Note: While arguably conclusive, this *is* speculation]

> This might just be a case of two students who are doing the same course

Compare the following present in both questions:

**unlimited4311's question**

```
String filename = "/Users/DAndre/Desktop/events.txt";
```

**unlimited43111's question**

```
String fileName = ("/Users/DAndre/Desktop/events.txt");
```

If they are two different students, they're doing the same homework *on the same computer* :P

(which is possible, but given the other data which makes it look like the same user, I'd say it is - again, I'm speculating here)

---

There is also similar text between the two questions.

The main bit is:

*unlimited4311*
"years in it like 1998, 1928, and etc."

*unlimited43111*
"list of dates like 1998, 1882, and etc."

"*, and etc*" - using "and" before "etc" like that is not common. Smells like a quick edit to change one of those dates.

Comment: Thanks for the sleuthing - that makes it pretty clear its the same user. So what is the recommended action (if any) or should we just ignore and move on?

Comment: AKAIK the system should find same IPs on different accounts (not sure how that works, or what delay etc). Just flag it for mod attention. They can see more than we can and investigate with more tools.

Comment: OK have gone ahead and flagged with reason "other" as it seems a reasonable response to help fight against the flood of poor *"please do my homework questions"*

Comment: Yeah, plus those you linked to have typical comments "I do not know/understand, give me more info", and moaning/arguing about the good info they did get. You can't help some people... FYI see first comment here by a mod - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103689/two-accounts-same-person

Comment: OK good to see that flagging this sort of thing is acceptable just needed clarification as I know the emphasis is usually on judge the "question" not the "poster".

Comment: Judging the question not the poster is correct when it's about content (ie "a question" is bad/poor/off-topic etc, not the poster for posting it) and that's because when you flag or vote (etc) on content (comments, question, answers) the site's functions sort it out (ie a ban if user has too many closed questions etc). But this case it's the posters actions away from content.

Comment: Also on the same user account, it would seem. I think you should move the actual answer (about flagging) to either the beginning or end of this post, so it'll be more visible for those skimming.

Comment: @jpmc26 good point ta

Comment: " they are two different students, they're doing the same homework on the same computer :P"  non sequitur. They can be on different computers with a user account with the same name.

Comment: @BartoszKP I did say "While arguably conclusive, this is speculation". It being arguably conclusive is from the unlikelihood of two different people having the same Stack username barring a single digit, with the same home PC username, doing the same homework, with similar writing styles, asking the same question on Stack. That's some crazy odds...

Answer (score 3):

If possible, flag it as a duplicate.

If you're really worried about it, additionally flag it for moderator attention and clearly explain that you think the two users are the same person.

That said, chances are good that if the moderators take any action at all, they will just merge the two accounts and close the duplicate.

Comment: I tried flagging it as a duplicate, but could not because there were no upvoted or accepted answers. Have edited question to mention this.

Comment: @MattCoubrough it seems you're right... Just flag for mod attention. Be sure to clearly explain what you think the problem is and what you want them to do about it.