# User asking low quality/poor research questions and creating new account weekly

Tags: support

I can't really prove this is happening, but it seems somebody is asking poor quality / unanswerable questions (usually about Gtk). After this user gets downvoted / banned (or in some cases gets rep), (s)he stops using that account and creates a new one.

And in the meantime, I found this [answer about the poor question dilemna](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278230/what-to-do-when-someone-keeps-creating-new-accounts-to-ask-the-same-bad-question).

And a discussion about [blocking new accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349531/is-it-possible-or-meaningful-to-forbid-someone-to-create-a-new-account-to-get).

I think I understand these concepts pretty good.

My question is: Do any of the higher ups (mods) have the tools to link accounts together *if* they actually come from the same person? I initially decided not to post on Meta, until this suspicious person specifically asked for my email address, since he thought I was really good at Gtk. Basically, I don't want to judge a newbie for a long time spammer, and yet I don't want SO cluttered with junk spread by one person using multiple accounts.

Again, my question is: Do the tools exist to link accounts together? And how do I trigger an investigation?

Thanks.

Comment: Raise a custom flag on one of their questions and explain what you think is happening. IIRC, there are ways for them to tell this is happening.

Comment: We won't link accounts together unless a user specifically requests it, but we *do* have tools that allow us to investigate and deal with the problem. So yes, if you see something that concerns you, please raise a moderator flag.